# postgresql operator negator usage

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, datatypes

I'm wondering if the negator clause of `CREATE OPERATOR` specifies how the negator *can* be interpreted, or how it *will* be interpreted. For example, if I have an operator `>=` and I set the negator to the operator `<`, will `NOT(x >= y)` always be interpreted as `x < y`, or does it just mean that it will be interpreted that way when it's advantageous.

I'm asking because I'd like to be able to be able to use `NOT(x op y)` in my queries as something other than the complement of `x op y`.  Is this possible and/or would it be playing with fire?

Concretely, I have a composite type with a subcolumn `match_id` and a subcolumn `second`.  I want to be able to use, for example, `NOT(x >= y)` to mean `x.match_id = y.match_id AND x.second < y.second`, which would be encoded in the operator `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with [PostgreSQL documentation about Negators:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xoper-optimization.html)

> 36.13.2. **NEGATOR**
>
> The NEGATOR clause, if provided, names an operator that is the negator of the operator being defined. We say that operator A is the negator of operator B if both return Boolean results and (x A y) equals NOT (x B y) for all possible inputs x, y. Notice that B is also the negator of A. For example, < and >= are a negator pair for most data types. An operator can never validly be its own negator.
>
> [...]

The way the `NEGATOR` is supposed to behave does *not* match your intended usage. I guess this could result in some execution plans **not giving the intended results**.

Again, according to the docs:

> Providing a negator is very helpful to the query optimizer since it allows expressions like NOT (x = y) to be simplified into x <> y. This comes up more often than you might think, because NOT operations can be inserted as a consequence of other rearrangements.

The way the text has been written, I understand that this implies that the planner *might* simpify a clause like `NOT(a op b)` into `a negator_op b` (or even the other way around, as commented out by [@craig-ringer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7788/craig-ringer)); but it also *might not* do it. The planner is *allowed to* make the simplification, but not *coerced to* or *has an obligation to* perform the conversion.

I suggest that, if you need different kind of comparisons, that you create *other opeartors*  (let's say `<%` `>%` `<=%` `>=%` or something like that), with corresponding negators if they make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Based on their language, I think you're right.

Comment: It might also choose to replace the negator with the original operator.